# Cocedeption with Laravel 5 exception when running functional and acceptance tests

Tags: laravel-5, codeception

I have a really simple test:

```
public function tryToGetJsonDataForAnItem(FunctionalTester $I)
{
    $I->wantTo('Test if correct JSON is returned');
    $I->sendPOST('/series/series', ['itemId' => 1]);
}
```

When I run the functional or acceptance tests with code coverage like this:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run functional tests/functional/frontend/SeriesCest.php:tryToGetJsonDataForAnItem --env testing --coverage-html
```

I get the following error:

```
file_get_contents(http://domain.dev/c3/report/clear): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

After some googling I found out, that this is because *remote* coverage is set to **true**. I set it to **false**. This is how my coverage part of the *codeception.yml* looks like:

```
coverage:
  enabled: true
  remote: false
  whitelist:
    include:
      - app/*
    exclude:
      - app/Events/*
      - app/Exceptions/*
      - app/Providers/*
```

And this is my **functional.suite.yml**

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
  modules:
  enabled: [Laravel5, Db, \Helper\Functional, REST]
  config:
    Laravel5:
      url: http://domain.dev
      cleanup: false
    REST:
      depends: PhpBrowser
     url: http://domain.dev
```

**Note:** If I run the tests without test coverage, they pass.

Comment: It happens because PhpBrowser is used in the same suite. I will raise an issue in https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Comment: Have you got a good reason to use REST module with PhpBrowser and not with Laravel5 module?

Comment: I changed my mind, this is not a bug of Codeception. If you use REST module over HTTP, you need a c3.php in the server. Setting remote: false only tells Codeception that tests are running on the same server and it doesn't have to copy code coverage results across the network.

Comment: @Naktibalda you are right. One of my problems was that I am using PhpBrowser instead of Laravel5 in the REST.depends config. I included the c3.php file in my **public/index.php** and it's finally working. I just don't quite get what **remote coverage** actually does. Everything is in my Homestead, so shouldn't it be local coverage? This is still a bit of a mistery to me.

Comment: http://codeception.com/docs/11-Codecoverage#Local-Server

Comment: Have you got a good reason to use PhpBrowser instead of Laravel5?

Comment: @Naktibalda no. It was my mistake. As I said in my previous comment, I changed it to Laravel5 and included the c3.php file and now it works. Thanks a lot for the help